# wordpress woocommerce template file overiding

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I am using [woocommerce](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/woocommerce/) to develop an ecommerce store. Everything is fine with woocommerce. But I have one problem. As because I want to show some custom images with some texts in the product page(shop based page). So for that I thought [wordpress advanced custom fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) will be good. I made it install. And now I need to extract the image in the template file. But by going through woocommerce plugin I got that it doesn't use the wordpress template. Woocommerce is generating the total page (producr page) by itself. And Iwant to show some custom fields from [wordpress advanced custom fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks...

**I want that woocommerce shop page where all the products are shown should use my own custom template. So that I can use wordpress advanced custom fields code there**

Comment: Note for other readers, this question was also asked here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88033/woocommerce-shop-page-to-use-my-custom-template

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve this problem, but this is considered a "BAD PRACTICE" in terms of scalability and extendability. Almost all of the wordpress/woocommerce developers follow a standard blueprint (i.e standard html markups, classes, ids etc.). Replacing the standard blueprint of wordpress/woocommerce with your own stuff, will only breaks everything and creates more bugs down the road! Also you won't be able to use other developers plugins/codes because you're not using the standard woocommerce while plugins would hook into the standard markups. It's simply NOT A GOOD IDEA!

Answer (score 5):

In order to override a Woocommerce template from `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates`, create a file with the same name in `wp-content/themes/<your theme>/woocommerce`. It will be used instead of the original one.

If you look at [one of the original template files](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product.php), you will actually find this instruction in a comment at the top:

> Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product.php

Comment: thanks for the reply but when I just made copy the woocommerce template folder and pasted it in my theme folder and using the advanced custom fields plugins to override shop page to show some images it is not showing there..Can you help me out? – when I just uninstalled the woocommerce plugin then the custom image from advanced custom fields is showing

Comment: Can you explain what kind of modification you want in your shopping page?/

Answer (score 4):

WooCommerce doesn't use normal template files from your theme (it uses the header and footer etc but the bulk of the actual interior content is split into a lot of Woo template files).

You can copy the templates out of the `plugins/woocommerce/templates` directory and move them to the `themes/yourtheme/woocommerce` directory to override (just pick the ones you need).

A list of all the templates [can be found here](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/template-structure/).  A list of useful php hooks/filters to use for more advanced customization [can be found here](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/extending/hooks/).  Other useful resources are the [CSS structure doc](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/css-structure/) and this [list of conditional template tags](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/theming/conditional-tags/) for WC.

There is kind of lackluster documentation for nitty-gritty theme development for WC so you will probably need to take some time to experiment with the templates in order to accomplish what you want, but it's decently commented and pretty easy to work with once you learn your way around.

Comment: @Ennui thanks fro the reply but when I just made copy the woocommerce template folder and pasted it in my theme folder and using the advanced custom fields plugins to override shop page to show some images it is not showing there..Can you help me out? – when I just uninstalled the woocommerce plugin then the custom image from advanced custom fields is showing

Comment: The ACF plugin is made to work with normal Wordpress posts/pages. Woocommerce product pages use their own template file, which might not work with ACF out of the box. You should check out [how to manually output custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields#Displaying_Custom_Fields) in a template.

Answer (score 1):

For products page and any part of your site that shows products like home page or category page the code responsible for it exists in woocommerce-template.php
line 29

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop'); ?>

                <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                    <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

                <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

                <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop'); ?>

            <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

                <?php woocommerce_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

            <?php endif;
```

you can use hooks and filters to change some part or you can override the function itself in **themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/functions.php** 
also you can edited directly but this is not advisable as you will lose changes after any upgrade.

Notice that in line 71 this function use template file content-product.php that is The template for displaying product content within loops and can be override  by copying it to **yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php**

Answer (score 1):

I found a great list of free woocommerce plugins, and some customization tips. Maybe it will be of some help.
http://fivera.net/woocommerce-customization-free-wp-plugins/

Comment: Could you provide a specific plugin that solves the question being asked, instead of providing a link to some other site?