# How to change the 'select options' text on button hover on the shop page for woocommerce?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change the text on the button that appears when hovering over an item on the shop page for my Wordpress/Woocommerce site. I have searched through many posts but cannot find a solution. I am using the ShopIsle theme. How can I change this select options text to 'view product'?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wordpress woocommerce template file overiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025213/wordpress-woocommerce-template-file-overiding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 2.1+ then this should work for you

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );    // 2.1 +

function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {

    return __( 'My Button Text', 'woocommerce' );

}
```

For woocommerce < 2.1

```
add_filter( 'add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );    // < 2.1

function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {

    return __( 'My Button Text', 'woocommerce' );

}
```

Comment: this also didn't work... I might not have linked my child theme to my main theme properly... is there a way to check this?

Comment: You can override any template in child theme and see if that is getting overridden. Because this solution is what woocommerce recommends. There is some issue with your theme.

Comment: If you want to debug this, then you can activate twenty seventeen theme and put this code there. If you see the text changed, then there is conflict with your child theme.

Comment: I hadn't linked the child theme properly - thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the child theme functions.php file and you can change the text on any of the buttons.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' , 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' );
/**
 * custom_woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart
*/
function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text() {
global $product;

$product_type = $product->product_type;

switch ( $product_type ) {
    case 'external':
        return __( 'Buy product', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
    case 'grouped':
        return __( 'View products', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
    case 'simple':
        return __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
    case 'variable':
        return __( 'Select options', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
    default:
        return __( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the above to check stock status and bring it to the add to cart text. See below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );

function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {

global $product;

$product_sstatus = $product->get_stock_status();

switch ( $product_sstatus ) {
case 'instock':
    return __( 'Add to Cart', 'woocommerce' );
break;
case 'outofstock':
    return __( 'Sold Out', 'woocommerce' );
break;
case 'onbackorder':
    return __( 'On Backorder', 'woocommerce' );
break;
default:
    return __( 'More Info', 'woocommerce' );

}}
```